# Where can I download non-malicious .EXE files for my machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, metadata

I have been working on a machine learning project which detects malware. I  have downloaded malicious files and tested my model and I was looking for a place which would contain about 50-60 non-malicious .EXE files.

Answer (score 1):

You can search google by filetype, so if any of these filetypes are appropriate

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en

> You can use the filetype: operator in Google Search to limit results to a specific file type. For example, [filetype:rtf galway](http://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:rtf%20galway) will search for RTF files with the term "galway" in them.

Then just right-click on each result, to save locally. For 50 files, this is an easy way to get diverse file formats.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just search for and copy all the .exe files from your C:\ drive to your sample data directory.

(My current C: partition has 3760 of them).

Answer (score 0):

FFIEC.gov offers Home Disclosure Mortgage Act exes: [HDMA exe files](https://www.ffiec.gov/hmda/hmdaraw.htm)
Not 50-60, but a definitive, non-malicious start to building your dataset.
Description of exes: 'HMDA LAR & TS Raw Data Windows Application
This software includes the loan-level data, documentation, and a tool to query and export the data.'